# Solutions of linear ODE with quadratic coefficients (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I am interested in the linear differential equation:

$$ \dot{x}(t) = (A t^2 + Bt + C) x(t)$$

where $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}_{n \times n}$ and $x(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Does anyone know about the solvability of such an equation?  Also, I am particularly interested in the case every matrix $A, B, C$ is skew symmetric if this helps.  If anyone has a reference to the study of such an equation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
Additional details:
```

Let's say for now I can solve $\dot{x}(t) = (At + B)x(t)$ for any $A$ and $B$.  Can I use this in any way to help me solve the above equation?

Comment: Is $x^{(1)} = \dot x$?

Comment: yes it is, i'll edit the post